# VS 2015 keeps changing TargetOfficeVersion in CSPROJ project file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, office365

We have a C# MVC web project. It connects to SharePoint online to retrieve some files. We do that through a reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI. There is file in GAC. They are related to a KB update of Office, as far as I can tell.

We have several developers using apparently the same installs of Windows 10 and Office 2016, both with all latest updates. Regrettably, every time one PC opens the project, the VS 2015 changes the csproj line:

```
 <TargetOfficeVersion>16.1</TargetOfficeVersion>
```

The change is 16.1 becomes 15.0. On the other PCs, it goes back to 16.1. We do not see any issue in any of the machines compiling or running the code. But imagine the frustration in git, when each commit contains this. GAC has both versions. the bin folder gets the 16.1 version.

We switched to using NuGet package for 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client'. The project points to it only and it is 16.1.5026.1200. The bin folder still also gets that version. Still, on one of the computers the VS 2015 changes it to 15.0 every time we load or run the project.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, we realize now that the add-in project had in its CSPROJ file the same tag TargetOfficeVersion but pointing to 15.0. This was automated from the VS template but also self inflicted.